# Determining a straight line equation from 2 cartesian coordinates

Tags: java, algorithm, math, coordinates, cartesian

I can do this on paper easily enough but have a bit of a mental block in getting this into a language (I'd take any answer but Java probably easiest).

I have two sets of points Point A (xA, yA) and Point B (xB, yB).

Knowing this, and assuming that these two create a straight line graph I need to be able write a function that will give me xC given that I would know yC (and, obviously that the new point is on the same line).

All help appreciated :)

Kind Regards

Comment: "I can do this on paper but not in Java" doesn't make much sense to me.  If it were a hard algorithm, ok (or if you were having trouble because of integer division).  But transforming an equation on paper to an equation in Java isn't that hard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(yB-yA)/(xB-xA) = (yC - yA) / (xC-xA)
```

you just have to obtain `xC` now, that is

```
xC = xA + ((yC - yA) * (xB-xA) / (yB-yA))
```

This is, assuming that `yB` is different from `yA` . If they are equal, then you have not solutions if `yC` is different from `yA`, and infinite solutions ( every `xC` works) if `yC=yA`

Comment: Thanks, god knows why I found that so hard! Total mental block! :)