# How do I animate my java Swing graphics2d component

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a gravity simulator and I need it animate live so the user can watch it. I've been able to make it trace out the path the object would take.

[image: Image of an orbit produced]

But as you can see it just traces it out and then displays the window. I think my problem is because all of this in the section of code that builds the JPanel but I don't know how to change it properly.

Here's what I'm doing for my window:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.Math;


public class Universe {
      
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {
        new Universe();       
    }

    public Universe() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Gravity Simulator");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }
        int paneWidth = 500;
        int paneHeight = 500;
               
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(paneWidth, paneHeight);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)  {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int size = Math.min(getWidth()-4, getHeight()-4) / 10;
            int width = getWidth() - (size * 2);
            int height = getHeight() - (size * 2);
            int x0=paneWidth/2; int y0=paneHeight/2; int radius0=20;

            int y = (getHeight() - (size * 10)) / 2;
            for (int horz = 0; horz < 2; horz++) {
                int x = (getWidth() - (size * 10)) / 2;
                for (int vert = 0; vert < 10; vert++) {
                    g.drawRect(x, y, size, size);
                    
                    drawCircle(g, x+25, y+25, 5);//A massive object would go here this just proof of concept
                    x += size;
                }
                y += size;
            }
                         
            double[] velocity={5,-2};
            MassiveObject planet = new MassiveObject(g, 20, 50, velocity, 250, 150);
            planet.draw(g);
            MassiveObject rock = new MassiveObject(g, 2, 25, velocity, 275, 300);
            rock.draw(g);

            double sGravity = fGrav(planet, rock);
            //double dis = massDis(planet, rock);
            System.out.println("Distance: "+massDis(planet, rock));
            System.out.println("Gravity: "+sGravity+" Newtons of force(gravity is multiplied by "+1000000+")");

            double[] traj = objectTrajetory(planet, rock, rock.getMass());
            int t = 0;
            
            try {
                while(true) {
                    //double k = sGravity/dis;
                    //x and y components of motion
                    double xm = traj[0];
                    double ym = traj[1];               
                    
                    double[]  nVelocity= {xm,ym};
                    //////////////////////////////
                    //set new position of object
                    rock.setX(rock.getX()+(xm));
                    rock.setY(rock.getY()+(ym));
                    rock.setVelocity(nVelocity);
                    rock.draw(g);
                    t++;
                    System.out.println("position changed: "+rock.getCoords());
                    traj = objectTrajetory(planet, rock, 1);
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    if (t> 15){break;}                    
                }
              }
              catch(Exception e) {
                
              }
               
            //System.out.println("Distance: "+massDis(planet, rock));
            //System.out.println("Gravity: "+fGrav(planet, rock)+" Newtons of force(gravity is multiplied by "+1000000+")");
              
            g2d.dispose();
        }
```

And here is the code for the draw function of my MassiveObject:

```
    public void draw(Graphics g){
  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
  Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(this.x0-(this.radius/2), this.y0-(this.radius/2), this.radius, this.radius);

  g2d.setColor(Color.GRAY);
  g2d.fill(circle);
}
```

So basically what I'm asking is how can I make it run that algorithm to paste the MassiveObject at its new location after the window is already pulled up so the user can watch it happening instead of it just building the window with it already on it?

Comment: You're doing way way too much in the paintComponent method.  The paintComponent method should paint your two bodies.  Period.  The orbital calculations should take place outside the drawing code.

Comment: You should NOT have a "while true" loop in a painting method. The purpose of the painting method is to paint the current state of the component, not alter the state. If you want animation the use a Swing Timer to schedule the animation at which point you alter the state and then invoke repaint() on the component.

Comment: Some examples that might help: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47394615/3992939) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61379584/3992939)

Answer (score 0):

The *logic* of your animation shouldn't be in the `paintComponent()` method. The `paintComponent()` method should just paint the current frame of animation. The code inside `paintComponent()` is run inside a special thread dedicated to handling all UI paints, responding to clicks etc. So for as long as `paintComponent()` is running, nothing else can happen in the UI, hence your application "grinds to a halt".

The logic to periodically update the state and then order a repaint should be in a separate thread (or the main thread). When it has updated the state and needs the next frame to be drawn, it then calls the panel's `repaint()` method. Because you're doing this in another thread, you would surround it in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. This orders Swing to to call back into the `paintComponent()`:

```
 while (true) {
   // Update state used by the paintComponent() method
   updateObjectPositions();

   // Now draw the new animation frame
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        universePanel.repaint(0, 0, universeWidth, universeHeight);
   });

   Thread.sleep(...);
 }
```

Because the drawing and updating are happening in different threads, you need to make sure that the data is shared between the threads in a thread-safe way. If you're just starting out and the calculations are very quick, then you could put the `updateObjectPositions()` method inside the `invokeLater()` so that the update to the data and the redraw happen in the UI thread. But remember that the code inside the `invokeLater()` will be blocking the UI for as long as it runs, so it should be as brief as possible and just handle a single frame. Crucially, your `while` loop and `sleep` should *not* go inside the `invokeLater()` or inside any UI code such as `paintComponent()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm very new to java, especially Swing and AWT. So you're saying I just need to utilize the paintComponent to paint the current state of the object, run my code to update the position, and then call the repaint to paint the new current state? And I assume that would go in the main thread where I'm creating the new Universe right?

Comment: Yes, paintComponent() should just paint the current state. It will be called by "the system" whenever the UI needs to be painted for some reason (including if e.g. a window covering your window is moved out the way). But crucially, it is just *painting*. It shouldn't include any logic to update the positions of things. Think of paintComponent() as the method that 'the system can call into at any time that it wants if it needs to determine how to paint the current contents of your window, for whatever reason'.

Comment: The actual logic to periodically update the positions of things could go in your main thread, if that thread doesn't need to do anything else. Or it could go in its own thread. You'd typically put that kind of logic in the main thread if you have a simple application that is just "doing one thing", logically speaking. You'd typically put it in a different thread if you have a more complex application that needs to do "multiple things at the same time". For example, imagine an application that could run multiple simulations simultaneously: each one might run in its own thread.

Comment: The call to repaint() goes in the main thread (or special logic thread) just after you've updated the positions. When you call repaint() you're saying to Swing: "please note the fact that this component needs to be repainted; when you get chance, in the UI thread, please call the paintComponent() method".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the help, I was able to get the program animating the way I wanted it to and it was exactly as you all suggested. I removed my logic from the paintComponent() and put it inside the JPanel pane, ran a timer to continuously update the position, and then ran the repaint() function at the end of each loop in timer.

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    int paneWidth = 1200;
    int paneHeight = 1200;

    double[] velocity={4,4};
        MassiveObject planet = new MassiveObject( 50, 50, velocity, paneWidth/2,paneHeight/2);
        MassiveObject rock = new MassiveObject( 2, 25, velocity, 150, 200);
        double[] traj = objectTrajetory(planet, rock, rock.getMass());
        double xm=0.00;
        double ym=0.00;

    public TestPane() {


        Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                xm = traj[0];
                ym = traj[1];
                double[]  nVelocity= {xm,ym};
                //////////////////////////////
                //set new position of object
                rock.setX(rock.getX()+(xm));
                rock.setY(rock.getY()+(ym));
                rock.setVelocity(nVelocity);
                
                
                System.out.println("position changed: "+rock.getCoords());
                repaint();
                traj = objectTrajetory(planet, rock, 1);
                rock.setX(rock.getX()+(xm));
                rock.setY(rock.getY()+(ym));

                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }
    
    



    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(paneWidth, paneHeight);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)  {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        int size = Math.min(getWidth()-4, getHeight()-4) / 10;
        int width = getWidth() - (size * 2);
        int height = getHeight() - (size * 2);
        int x0=paneWidth/2; int y0=paneHeight/2; int radius0=20;

        
        rock.draw(g);
        planet.draw(g);
        
        g2d.dispose();
        
    }
```

The program now animates pretty smoothly instead of just spitting out a plot of the path it would take.

[Snap of Animated Orbit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHOzI.png)